# ignore all changes to dir

Tags: git-merge, git-submodules, git-stage

We have a git submodule, it's in a folder called 'config' in several repos.

I am getting this when doing a merge:

```
On branch oleg/feature/1537299444
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/oleg/feature/1537299444'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   config (modified content)

no changes added to commit
```

and it exits with 1.

How can I ignore all changes to the 'config' folder, which is a gitsubmodule?

I tried:

```
git checkout config
```

but that didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to check what kind of of diff/new element you see in the submodule.

```
cd config
git status
git diff
```

If you can, do a `git reset --hard` in that config folder (if you don't need any local modification done in config)

Then go back to the parent repo, and retry your `git merge`.